# Java, delete blob file after it passes through BlobTrigger

Tags: java, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage, azure-storage

I am using AzureFunctions, AzureStorageExplorer and Java.
After uploading a blob file it activates the blob trigger and runs code.

After it runs, I wish for the file that I uploaded to be deleted.
How do I delete the passed blob file from the storage container.

```
@FunctionName("import-import")
public void run(
        @BlobTrigger(
                name = "import",
                dataType = "binary",
                path = "import/containers/{name}",
                connection = "SourceStorage"
        ) final byte[] content,
        @BindingName("name") final String filename,
        final ExecutionContext context
) {
    final Logger logger = context.getLogger();
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35708355/java-azure-storage-client-deleting-blobs

Comment: Can you use the Java SDK from within the Azure Function to make a connection to the storage account and delete the object?